# Cannot get to $rootScope

Tags: angularjs

The following file "works" (the sense that it does not throw any errors):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="modx">
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0rc7.js"></script> 
    <script>
        angular.module("modx", [], function($routeProvider) {
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

but this

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="modx">
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0rc7.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module("modx", [], function($routeProvider, $rootScope) {
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

gives the error:

> Error: Unknown provider: $rootScope from modx
>   Source File: http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0rc7.js
>   Line: 2491

WTF?

Comment: +1 for WTF as the bottom line.

Answer (score 307, accepted):

You can not ask for instance during configuration phase - you can ask only for providers.

```js
var app = angular.module('modx', []);

// configure stuff
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  // you can inject any provider here
});

// run blocks
app.run(function($rootScope) {
  // you can inject any instance here
});
```

See http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module for more info.

Comment: Thanks, it makes perfect sense, but how did you know that?  Was it in the docs?

Comment: @Mavolio No, he is one the 3 core developers.

Comment: Well, FWIW, it is in the docs now, under the "Module Loading & Dependencies" section.

Comment: @vojta But what if I need to pass parameter from outside and use it in `config` ? say root path within asp.net app ? I just don't want to use global variables and wanted to use `ng-init='root:<%= myroot %>'` and use `root` value into `module.config`.

Comment: @vittore not sure I understand - but if the value from outside is in the global state (say on window), you can just read it from there... You can't access global window from Angular expression (that's intentional).

Comment: @Vojta my point is that using `ng-init="root:'\local\js\app'"` (where this root is dynamic and inserted when html page renders) seemed to be reasonable way of passing param into angular app, but i can't access this `root` value in config.

Comment: @vittore I think, putting this "outside" config into the global window is fine. Or having one module that defines all this stuff and then you  load it in your app - eg. `angular.module('config', []).constant('appRoot', '/local/js/app');` (this code would be generated by your server (you could even generate it as a JS file, rather then inlining into the html file). Then, your app loads this module and therefore has access to `appRoot`.

Comment: How to use services like `$location`  `$state`  in config() block ? or how to change `$state.param` in run() block?

Answer (score 7):

I've found the following "pattern" to be very useful:

```
MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', 'socket', ...];
function MainCtrl (scope, rootscope, location, thesocket, ...) {
```

where, MainCtrl is a controller. I am uncomfortable relying on the parameter names of the Controller function doing a one-for-one mimic of the instances for fear that I might change names and muck things up. I much prefer explicitly using $inject for this purpose.

Comment: That's neat; but how do you access `MainCtrl` like that?

Comment: I know your comment is old but it is worth responding to questions for future's sake.  Modules/controllers can be defined like this so you can access them in this way:
`angular.module('myMod', []).controller('theController', controllerFunction);

controllerFunction.$inject = [];
function controllerFunction() { 
}`

Answer (score 1):

I **don't suggest** you to use syntax like you did. AngularJs lets you to have different functionalities as you want (`run`, `config`, `service`, `factory`, etc..), which are more professional.In this function you don't even have to inject that by yourself like

```
MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', 'socket', ...];
```

you can use it, as you know.