# angularjs using variables in templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to use `$scope` in my templateUrl like this:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/blog', {
                templateUrl: 'themes/{{ mainCtrl.site_theme }}/view/home.html',
                controller: 'BlogMain',
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/blog'
        })
}]);
```

When trying to use:

`root/themes/<theme_name>/view/home.html` as the template file. It currently gives me the error `GET http://www.url.com/themes/%7B%7B%20mainCtrl.site_theme%20%7D%7D/view/home.html 404 (Not Found)`

NOTE: it works fine if I type the theme name normally

Any help will be appreciated :D thanks in advance

Comment: `'themes/{{ mainCtrl.site_theme }}/view/home.html'` should be `'themes/' + 'mainCtrl.site_theme' + '/view/home.html'`. Since this code won't execute as a template, `{{ }}` won't work, if I am correct.

Comment: cheers for the reply, this just gives me another error `mainCtrl is not defined`. ive read somewhere that you cant use $scope variables in your app.config but surely theres a way around using it (or an alternative)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**OPTION ONE**

You can set a variable (in your case the theme name) in the url and then access it in your routes:

```
.when('/blog/:themeName', {
     templateUrl: function(params) {
         return 'themes/'+ params.themeName +'/view/home.html',
     }
```

This probably less suited to your situation though as it isn't ideal passing your theme name via the URL. I'd recommend option two...

**OPTION TWO**

You can use a provider to allow the setting of the theme name:

```
app.provider('themeConfig', function() {
    this.name = 'Default';
    this.$get = function() {
        var name = this.name;
        return name;
    };
    this.setName = function(name) {
        this.name = name;
    };
});
```

You can now inject the provider into your application config, set the theme and then use it in your routes.

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', 'themeConfigProvider', 
   function ($routeProvider, themeConfigProvider) {

      themeConfigProvider.setName('mytheme');

      $routeProvider
          .when( '/this', { templateUrl: themeConfigProvider.name + '-this.html' })
          .when( '/that', { templateUrl: themeConfigProvider.name +'-that.html' })
          .when( '/other', { templateUrl: themeConfigProvider.name +'-other.html' })
          .otherwise( { redirectTo: '/this' });
}]);
```

Working jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3B5Sk/

Answer (score 1):

During the configuration phase you can only ask for **providers** ($routeProvider, $locationProvider etc.) it means you **cannot** inject $scope instance. 
you can always inject any instance in the run phase.

**example:**

```
// configuration
app.config(function($routeProvider) {

});

//inject any instance 
 app.run(function($rootScope) {
      //your logic here
});
```

Take a look at the following stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10489658/1745230).

Answer (score 0):

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', 'themeStateProvider',
function ($routeProvider, themeStateProvider) {
    function getUrl(){
         return 'themes/' + themeStateProvider.currentTheme + '/view/home.html'
    }
    $routeProvider.
        when('/blog', {
                templateUrl: getUrl,
                controller: 'BlogMain',
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/blog'
        })
}]);
```

Then in controller you can inject themeState and update currentTheme property. This should work. currentTheme should property of the same object shared between provider and service.