# How can I inject scope inside of config

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material

I have been working with angularjs material now and I want to add scope inside of config file module. When I insert the scope it gives me error.
Is there way can I add scope element like this.

```
app.config(function($mdThemingProvider, $scope) {
    $scope.color = 'red'
    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
        .primaryPalette($scope.color)
};
```

I tried $provider method but i could not. Could you help me

Comment: Scope corresponds to an html view. Only angular controllers and directives can have the $scope access. Because, it simply does not make sense, what scope do you intend to give to the config? Scopes are with respect do html DOM and only controllers or directives have access to the respective scopes.

Comment: You can not ask for $scope during configuration phase. Not even $rootScope. Config is the phase that alters provider configuration.

Comment: I guess this is the wrong way to do it. There is no scope available in the 'config' lifecycle. A $scope is bound to a controller or a directive. If you wanna initialize some objects you could use app.run(function($rootScope){...})

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot get to $rootScope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486769/cannot-get-to-rootscope)

Comment: it will not working with run module I tried ...

Comment: it gives me injector error

Comment: https://material.angularjs.org/#/Theming/03_configuring_a_theme it only configuring with config module