# how to call $rootScope variable inside config function - angular

Tags: angularjs

i have a value inside $rootscope and i want to access this value inside the config function  , this is my code :

```
--run function 
myApp.run(function ($rootScope) {

$rootScope.myVariable = "my value";

});


--config function



myApp.config(['$provide','$routeProvider','$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',function($provide,$routeProvider,$stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {

    // here ,i want to access to myVariable value to do some tests
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector){

            var $state = $injector.get('$state');
            var $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');

               alert($rootScope.myVariable == "1");

            if ($rootScope.myVariable) {
                $state.go('mystat1'); 
            }
            else {
                 $state.go('mystat2');   
            }

        });

     }]);
```

any idea how to achieve this.

thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486769/cannot-get-to-rootscope#10489658

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Run blocks are executed after config blocks. You can not pass from .run to .config only the opposite direction

Comment: hey @Roman Koliada, my problem is, i can't get the value from my variable, and i need this value it to do some conditional  config , any suggestion please?.

Comment: @Ali, I don't see a problem, it just works: https://plnkr.co/edit/xxTpvxB9GSwAqy25s5GN?p=preview

Comment: hey @Roman Koliada, thank you so much, the problem, was in the order of calling the config() function and the run() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.config` block is exectuted before `.run`, try this [run and config order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663076/angularjs-app-run-documentation).

Comment: thank you @Itsik Mauyhas , the problem was in the order of calling, it works now.