# How to set a variable according to ui-view?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a `pageheader` template above angularjs's ui-view. I want to specify a variable `showDropdown` to control the appearence of some DOMs in `pageheader`. The `showDropdown` variable is specific with the `ui-view`. For example `showDropdown` is `true` in the first view, and `false` in the second view. How can I make it change according to ui-view?

I've tried to set the variable in the `onEnter()` of `stateProvider`, but has no influence.

HTML,

```
<pageheader></pageheader>
<br />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12 no-padding"><div ui-view="view"></div></div></div>
</div>
```

pageherder template,

```
<div>
......
</div>
<div ng-if="showDropdown">
  ........
</div>
```

JS,

```
.config(function($stateProvider)
{
    $stateProvider
        .state('printer',
        {
            url: "/printer",
            views:
            {
                "view":
                {
                    templateUrl: "/static/tpls/cloud/app/printer.php"
                }
            }，
            onEnter: function(){
                showDropdown = false;
            }
        })
        .state('control',
        {
            url: "/control",
            views:
            {
                "view":
                {
                    templateUrl: "/static/tpls/cloud/app/control.php"
                }
            }
        })
})
```

---

**Edit for [Pengyy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44275089/6521116)**

```
    app.controller('CloudController', ['$scope', '$http', '$interval', '$timeout', 'optSev', '$state', '$rootScope', function($scope, $http, $interval, $timeout, optSev, $state, $rootScope)
    {
        var search  = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var paras = search.split("&");
        paras = paras[0].split("=");
        pid = paras[1];
        $scope.pid = pid;
        $scope.active = {};
        $scope.idle = true;
        $scope.active.status = {};
        $scope.active.state = {};
        $scope.showDropdown = $state.current.showDropdown;
        //$scope.showDropdown = $rootScope.showDropdown;
//console.log($scope.showDropdown);
console.log($state);
console.log($state.current);
//console.log($state.$current);
.....
```

It's very weried,

```
console.log($state); // it shows the showDropdown
```

[image]

```
console.log($state.current); // the showDropdown is missed.
```

[image]

---

Comment: Try using $rootScope: `$rootScope.showDropdown = true`

Comment: @NinhPham [`$rootScope` cannot be accessed when instance during configuration phase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10489658/6521116)

Comment: do you want to show/hide `pageheader` component itself or part of it?

Comment: just a part of it

Comment: @PankajParkar part of it. is it a bad implementation here? I have not much experience in angularjs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply add `showDropdown` to your state config like below:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('printer',
    {
      url: "/printer",
      views:
      {
        "view":
        {
          templateUrl: "/static/tpls/cloud/app/printer.php"
        }
      }，
      showDropdown: false
    })
```

and retrieve it by `$state.current.showDropdown` in your controller.

---

demo **[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BYevwa?p=preview)**.

Comment: I add this line `showDropdown: false;`, but get `SyntaxError: missing } after property list`

Comment: @KrisRoofe  I'm really sorry, you have to remove `;`  :P

Comment: yeah, when moved the `;`, there is no such error. I'm testing if it works now.

Comment: In the controller I can see the 'showDropdown` in the `$state` variable, but not in the `$state.current`. I add the weired issue in my question.

Comment: @KrisRoofe where did you add the `console.log`?  It seems there are different states where you write `console.log`.

Comment: I eidt it in my question

Comment: @KrisRoofe sorry for late response, can you produce your problem with this plunker? https://plnkr.co/edit/BYevwa?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did not use controller for each ui-view. I just use app.controller.    https://plnkr.co/edit/8RPCpS?p=preview, when you navigate to Hello view, you can check the output of console.log.

Comment: @KrisRoofe I think this is not the correct usage for ui-view, but still you can deal it with `$state.get('printer').showDropdown`. :-)

Comment: I finally move `pageheader` into each uiview template, and add                  `controller: function($scope, $state) {
                            $scope.showDropdown = $state.current.showDropdown;
                        }` to `"view"`.